# Management.Automation requirements to run as sched task

Tags: c#, powershell, scheduled-tasks, runspace

I've written an application in C# using the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace to automate a task using Exchange Cmdlets.  The application uses a configured Username and password for the PSCredential set presented to open the Runspace, and works using it interactively.  The Runspace is launching a remote PS Session on an Exchange CAS array.

I've included the credential set in the "Local admin" and "Log in as Batch" roles, but cannot run the application using a Scheduled Task.  The service account credentials have access to the Exchange cmdlets.

The scheduled task "fires" as it should, but the application fails to initialize the runspace.

Does anyone know what is required of the service account credentials to enable running this as a scheduled task?

Comment: What kind of error messages are you seeing, if any at all? Can you post the code here. Have you tried running this outside of a scheduled job and do you see any issues? If the task fires without issue, then most likely it is in the code itself.

Comment: I can't post the code, but as mentioned, it works fine interactively.  I'm not thinking it is the code at this point.   The Task fires no problem, the task completes, no problem (no exceptions at least.)  However, the message generated when the runspace is opened, does not appear.  (I've put in a message to display the version of the runspace.)   I know that remoting with Exchange PowerShell has some tripwires or at least "gotchas" that if permissions are not right, nothing happens.  Sorry I can't be more specific, but I do appreciate you reply.

Comment: Still working on this issue.  Nothing more to report here, but I probably have some new things that won't work.